# What is the simplest way for ploting a TSP graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have created a very simple Traveling Salesman Problem`s algorithm and now I need to output the results in a visual garph.

I have a matrix with path weights and an correctly ordered array of points (the path)

The Internet is full of very complex and detailed examples of TSP (like for DNA research) yet I am looking for some basic plotting function.

Comment: if you know where each point should be, see gplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to plot, but assuming it is just the resulting path it is quite simple:

```
x=randperm(10); % Your x coordinates
y=randperm(10); % Your y coordinates
% Now plot these points and make sure you add 1 term to return to the starting point
plot([x x(1)],[y y(1)])
```